# CRM 2013 Change DB Owner

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

When you install CRM 2013 on-premise it sets the DB Owner of the databases to the installation account.  Is it supported to change the DB Owner after the install is finished and if so what are the required permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've done it multiple times in our Dev and QA environments when they get a refresh from Prod.  By default the owner of the DB is in a domain that doesn't exist, and so we get errors like this:

> Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): An error
>   occurred in the Microsoft .NET Framework while trying to load assembly
>   id 65536. The server may be running out of resources, or the assembly
>   may not be trusted with PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE.
>   Run the query again, or check documentation to see how to solve the
>   assembly trust issues. For more information about this error: 
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'microsoft.crm.sqlclr.helper, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. An error
>   relating to security occurred.

I can't speak to the actual rights but this is the query we've ran:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE Contoso_MSCRM SET TRUSTWORTHY ON

USE Contoso_MSCRM
GO

EXEC sp_changedbowner 'dev\crmdv2administrator'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Is crmdv2administrator an AD account or just a local user?

Comment: @GoBeavs It's an AD account that is an Admin in CRM, but I believe that just setting it to db_owner was all we really had to do.